# Bootstrap DateTimePicker set minimum time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have a bootstrap datetimepicker. It's current minimum time is whatever the time is in real time. I need the minimum time to be real time plus 20 minutes added. So if it is 2:30PM I need the minimum time allowed to be 2:50PM in the datetimepicker. How can I do this?

```
<div class="calender">                          
  <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>

  @section scripts {
    <script>
      $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
        minDate: new Date()                                      
      });
    </script>
  }                           
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In effect you're asking 'how can I add 20 minutes to the current Date?' To do that you can use `setMinutes()`, like this:

```
var minDate = new Date();
minDate.setMinutes(minDate.getMinutes() + 20);

$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
    minDate: minDate                                
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it simple, you can use moment.js because it supports a functionality of `add()`.

In your case, you can use `.add(20,'minutes')` or .`add(20, 'm')`.

Reference: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

else

```
var currentDateTime = new Date();
var newDateTime = currentDateTime.setMinutes(currentDateTime.getMinutes() +20); 
$('datetimepicker1').val(newDateTime);
```

Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/MKK2V/